# remove the <++> in the Vim-Latex

Tags: vim, latex

I am using the Vim-Latex now. But I have a question, when everytime I type the {***}, it would append <++> automatically? How can I disable it?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are intended as jump-positions, so you can easily continue editing without exiting insert-mode. To jump to and replace the next <++>, type ctrl+j while in insert or normal mode.

Answer (score 8):

To completely disable the use of place-holders, put `let g:Imap_UsePlaceHolders = 0` in your `.vimrc`. (You can also change this setting at runtime to enable or disable place-holders whenever you like.)

Information on this and other similar settings is included in the (pretty extensive) help file accompanying vim-latex, which should be available to you through `:help latex-suite` (if you've got everything installed correctly).